# I'm using Expo App in my Android Device to connect into the my Desktop's Expo

Tags: android, expo, adb

I'm using Expo App on my Android device to connect to my Desktop
(Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) Expo (I signed in both my same Expo Account)I am also connected to the same network. Then I scanned my code then after that, it was unable to connect it. This is the error:

```
java.net.connectexception failed to connect to expo
```

[image: exp]

- expo -V  5.4.3
- node -v  v18.1.0
  [image]